# double method keep return initial value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of rate, I want of the function I built it to calculate average of these rates and return it, but it keeps return me 0.0 (the initial value).

```
double getTotalRateForEveryTeacher({String teacherID}){

    double totalRate = 0.0;
    
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("rateTeachers").where("teacherID", isEqualTo: teacherID).get().then((snapshot){

      if(snapshot.docs.length == 0){
        totalRate = 0.0;
      }
      else{
        List.generate(snapshot.docs.length, (index){
          totalRate = totalRate + snapshot.docs[index]['rate'];
        });

        totalRate = totalRate / snapshot.docs.length;
      }
      
    });

    return totalRate;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

```
 Future<double> getTotalRateForEveryTeacher({String teacherID}) async {
    double totalRate = 0.0;

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("rateTeachers")
        .where("teacherID", isEqualTo: teacherID)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.docs.length == 0) {
        totalRate = 0.0;
      } else {
        List.generate(snapshot.docs.length, (index) {
          totalRate = totalRate + snapshot.docs[index]['rate'];
        });

        totalRate = totalRate / snapshot.docs.length;
      }

      return totalRate;
    });

    return totalRate;
    }
```

Step 2:

accessing the value

```
...getTotalRateForEveryTeacher().then((value) => print(value));
```

Comment: Keep return 0.0

Comment: @khaled09909 I have modified the answer please check with this.

Comment: Don't just post a block of code. Post an explanation on what the problem was and what was done to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Abion47 ! for your feedback. hereafter I will provide the content and also I will modifiy the provided answer with content.